# Can we destroy the current localStorage value if we opened the same URL on different Window?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two types of user roles in my app. One is admin and second one is super admin.

I want to open a new window with Signup link to register the admin from super admin dashboard.

So Is it possible to do that way?

I have used below code to open the signup link but it is redirected on super admin dashboard.

```
<a onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 
     'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">
    Signup
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by simple plain html, hope this helps:-

```
<a (click)="destroy()" href="https://yoururltoopen.com" target="_blank">Signup
</a>
```

and in the angular code in the $scope.destroy function do this to destroy local storage:-

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Click event will write like : `(click)="destroy()"`

Comment: I want to retain the localStorage value in my current window tab. when I switch to different window tab I want to destroy the localstorage.

Comment: Yes the above code will make you go to new window and delete the localStorage.

Comment: Agreed Asim, But when I refresh the page there is only one login at a time.

Comment: So then what you need is to dont clear current localStorage and move to new tab which has its own localStorage so that both the user's info can be there?

Comment: I have cleared the current Login locastorage value but in new window. Now I want to both can login user can see the dashboard at a time in two different window same as Gmail.

Comment: I think the localStorage from one browser is for one client only if another one logs in or something like that automatically the other opened tab will also be available as that user also.

Comment: Right. So can we open two login user in two different chrome window?

Comment: You can, in two different windows if one is incognito or private. Otherwise you can't open 2 users in two tabs or two windows.